# Why doesn't two hashmaps override values of each other?

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    HashMap<Integer, String> hashMap2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    hashMap1.put(1, "Ram");
    hashMap1.put(2, "Mitali");
    hashMap1.put(2, "Gaurav");

    hashMap2.put(1, "Ram");
    hashMap2.put(2, "Test");
    System.out.println("hashMap1 values : ");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : hashMap1.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Hashcode of " + entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getKey().hashCode());
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("hashMap2 values : ");
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : hashMap2.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Hashcode of " + entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getKey().hashCode());
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
hashMap1 values : 
Hashcode of 1:1
1:Ram
Hashcode of 2:2
2:Gaurav
hashMap2 values : 
Hashcode of 1:1
1:Ram
Hashcode of 2:2
2:Test
```

When the hashcode of all the keys from different maps is equal, and the keys are also equal, why aren't both maps being overriden to:

```
1, "Ram"
2, "Test"
```

The keys are equal plus the hashcode is also equal, but then why aren't they overwritten? This was asked to me in an interview and I couldn't answer.

Comment: because they are refering to two different instances of the hashMap

Comment: wouldn't it be wrong if they overwrite each other?

Comment: Thanks a ton. Cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because they are independent objects logically as well as physically. Consider if you want to add new value in one of the HashMap, will you expect it in another map?

Comment: Correct, I won't expect it to happen. There are two entities operating independently. This cleared my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your two HashMaps are different objects, each with its own keys and values. There is no reason to expect the keys and values in one to be over written by the keys and values in the other.